# AWS API Gateway Lambda authorizer REQUEST type does not have methodArn?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, .net-core-3.1, lambda-authorizer

Writing a custom API Gateway Lambda authorizer using C# and Im using the `REQUEST` authorizer (not TOKEN).  Looking at their [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-input.html) I should have an available parameter called `methodArn` but looking at the class `APIGatewayProxyRequest` it's not listed from their SDK.

Is this the correct input parameter to use for my lambda authorizer?

```
namespace Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents
{
    public class APIGatewayProxyRequest
    {
        public APIGatewayProxyRequest();

        public string Resource { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string HttpMethod { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> Headers { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, IList<string>> MultiValueHeaders { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> QueryStringParameters { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, IList<string>> MultiValueQueryStringParameters { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> PathParameters { get; set; }
        public IDictionary<string, string> StageVariables { get; set; }
        public ProxyRequestContext RequestContext { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool IsBase64Encoded { get; set; }

        <...SNIP...>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `APIGatewayCustomAuthorizerRequest` instead of `APIGatewayProxyRequest`.